# MySQL Fulltext search result relevance

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, relevance

I've the following 'banks' table

```
ID  | name

1   | JPMorgan Chase bank  
2   | Bank of south  
3   | Citigroup bank 
4   | Wells Fargo bank
5   | Bank of New York
```

So when searches for 'bank of' I want the search result to return as follows:

```
Bank of New York
Bank of south
Citigroup bank
JPMorgan Chase bank
Wells Fargo bank
```

But with my code below it returns:

```
JPMorgan Chase bank
Bank of America
Citigroup bank
Wells Fargo bank
Bank of New York
```

This is the code:

```
$search_term = 'bank of';

$sql2 = "SELECT *, 
         MATCH(name) AGAINST ('.$search_term.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
         AS relevance FROM banks
         HAVING relevance > 0.8 
         ORDER BY relevance DESC";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider this: *Words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match.*

Comment: @juergend, right but what are my choices?

Comment: Two character words such as 'of' will not be indexed by the MySQL FullText indexes as the minimum word length is restricted to 3 characters in InnoDB tables and 4 characters in MyISAM tables. Read more here. In a situation where you have the access to change the minimum word length to 2 characters should give you expected results.

Answer (score 1):

> *...right but what are my choices?*

You can try something like this

```sql
SELECT *, 
       MATCH(name) AGAINST ('bank of' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance,
       name LIKE '%bank of%' AS full_match
  FROM banks
HAVING relevance > 0.8 
 ORDER BY full_match DESC, relevance DESC, name
```

Outcome:

```
| ID |                NAME | RELEVANCE | FULL_MATCH |
|----|---------------------|-----------|------------|
|  5 |    Bank of New York |         1 |          1 |
|  2 |       Bank of south |         1 |          1 |
|  3 |      Citigroup bank |         1 |          0 |
|  1 | JPMorgan Chase bank |         1 |          0 |
|  4 |    Wells Fargo bank |         1 |          0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60bff/2)** demo